# ExactTarget suppression list can't find members

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a subscriber list of about 50,000 employees. We need to exclude a certain division from these emails. We created a suppression list of email ids and subscriber keys in a CSV format. I imported the suppression list but it cannot find the members in the subscriber list. For all the members I get 'Not Found' error. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you checked the import report to verify the job was successful?

Comment: Yes, it is in the import report that I get the following.Results:

 Updated: 0

ValidationErrors: NotFound: 4126

Comment: How big is the suppression list you are uploading?

Comment: |From the reports, nothing was uploaded with 4126 failing . I suspect the size of your suppression list might match this

Comment: Your question states you created a csv file that included email id.  The reported fields for importing into a list are subscriber key and email address.  Not sure if that is what you meant by email id.

Comment: I would recommend manually mapping the fields in your import definition to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I have both subscriber key and email id in my csv file and when I import the suppression list I map both to the master list. I'm trying a different approach now. Any way to delete all emails with status != Active in the email list ?

Answer (score 1):

To delete all subscribers with a status different than active, I'd export All Subscribers, delete all active ones from that export and re-import (add and update) the rest of them to a list.
When imported to a list, I'd delete that list, and make sure to tick the option not only removing them from that list, but removing them from All Subscribers also.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, a good workaround. I just wish there was an easy way to do it within ExactTarget.